# Setting Response.StatusCode in View in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've just converted a project from MVC1 to MVC2. In the MVC1 project the HTTP status code was being set in some of the views. These views are now generating this exception:

Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

What has changed from MVC1 to MVC2 to cause this and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I would recommend you modifying this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you shouldn't be setting any status codes in the views at all.  Is this not the role of the controller at most?

Comment: Generally I would agree with you but this was a case where I was using the view from multiple locations in the Controllers and wanted to apply the DRY principal so I only wanted to set the Status Codes in one location.